# React Hooks - useDidUpdateEffect with deep compare

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I have the following useDidUpdateEffect hook

```
import { useRef, useEffect } from "react";

export default function useDidUpdateEffect(effect, deps) {
  const didMount = useRef(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (didMount.current) {
      effect();
    } else {
      didMount.current = true;
    }
  }, deps);
}
```

And I am currently using it as follows:

```
useDidUpdateEffect(() => { ... }, [JSON.stringify(complexNestedObject)]);
```

The problem is that, as my dep is complex and deep, sometimes the callback is being executed without being necessary.

I have one solution for useEffect, which is useDeepEffect:

```
import { useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import { isEqual } from "lodash";

export default function useDeepEffect(effect, deps = undefined) {
  const isFirst = useRef(true);
  const prevDeps = useRef(deps);

  useEffect(() => {
    const isSame = prevDeps.current.every((obj, index) =>
      isEqual(obj, deps[index])
    );

    if (isFirst.current || !isSame) {
      effect();
    }

    isFirst.current = false;
    prevDeps.current = deps;
  }, deps);
}
```

But I can't think of anything to do a deep compare with useDidUpdateEffect, without having to create another hook.

Any ideas?

====================

## UPDATE:

I am in this current situation because of this scenario. Maybe this could be done simpler, but to be honest, I tried my best (I am not super professional)

> 1. I have a folder "api" with different modules which contains different functions to connect to my server (I am not using hooks for
>    this part)

```
   services/
       firebase/
           api/
              users/
                 helpers/
                 cache/
                    usersCache.js
                 index.js
                 ...
```

As you can see, I have a module "usersCache.js" (memoization pattern) which will avoid some RTTs and reduce costs. To avoid problems with RAM, I have implemented there a caching algorithm "LRU".

> 2. In my app I am not using REDUX (maybe the worst idea I have taken, but too late to adapt it, 90% of the work is done. Will try to learn
>    this tech and adopt it in production, with a long refactoring).

To manage complex states, I am using React Context + useReducer, something that somehow simplifies my life, as it is a little similar to Redux.

In my case, for users I have 2 contexts:

1. CurrentUserContext
2. OtherUsersContext

Both of them contains sensitive and non-sensitive data of the fetched users. Here you may think: why to have the usersCache? If both contexts can be used as an in-memory cache?

The answer (at least what I think) is:

1. There is no way to consume contexts outside React components or hooks. Its not possible to do it inside my api modules in order to return cached data and avoid making server requests.
2. I am saving sensitive data in the contexts (isFollowed, for example) which depend on the current user session. So, when the user logs out, the contexts are unmounted (protected routes). In the other hand, my usersCache module is still there, with no sensitive data.

Here is an example of my CurrentUserContext (I am not using a reducer here because of simplicity, but in my OtherUsersContext, as state management is complex, I do):

```
import React, { createContext } from "react";

import useDidUpdateEffect from "../../hooks/useDidUpdateEffect";
import useStateWithCallback from "../../hooks/useStateWithCallback";
import { usersCache } from "../../services/firebase/api/users";

const CurrentUserContext = createContext(null);

export default CurrentUserContext;

export function CurrentUserProvider({ children }) {
  const [data, setData] = useStateWithCallback(undefined);

  const updateData = (data, merge = true, callback = undefined) => {
    if (merge) {
      setData((prevData) => ({ ...prevData, ...data }), callback);
    } else {
      setData(data, callback);
    }
  };

  useDidUpdateEffect(() => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
    /*
      As the current user data is not sensitive, we can
      synchronize the users cache here.
    */
    usersCache.updateCachedUser(data.id, data);
  }, [JSON.stringify(data)]); // TODO - Avoid unnecessary executions -> deepCompare ?

  return (
    <CurrentUserContext.Provider
      value={{
        data,
        setData,
        updateData,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </CurrentUserContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

To avoid running multiple useDidUpdateEffects, I am stringifying the user data. But, as it is complex and nested:

```
 userData = {
     avatar: {
         uri,
         thumbnailUri, 
     },
     ...
 }
```

the effect is executed when the data hasn't change, because of receiving the same data disordered:

```
userData = {
     avatar: {
         thumbnailUri,
         uri, 
     },
     ...
 }
```

**The top level fields are nor disordered.**

Comment: There's so much that's scary and wrong about what you're trying to do. `JSON.stringify(complexNestedObject)` is a huge red flag that something has gone off the rails here. What's your goal? What problem are you trying to solve? Not, "I've created these weird unmaintainable hooks that I need to fix" - but **why** did you create these weird unmaintainable hooks in the first place? To be honest, it smells like you've created them because you're just not understanding react correctly.

Comment: You may have taken a very difficult path that's going to render your code unmaintainable. The useEffect hook provided by react actually covers a lot of use cases that you do need not go beyond. Perhaps, if you explain in detail that which you need to do, the community will help you find a simpler solution.

Comment: @Adam I have a context provider that provides methods which update the stateful user data. I am using a reducer... so there is no way to await the dispatch, because it doesn't return a promise. So... as performing side effects inside pure functions is an anti-pattern, and the user data can change because of a lot of situations (pull-to-refreshes, actions in the frontend, etc etc) I have decided to use (in order to avoid a long list of useEffects) a unique useDidUpdateEffect that runs the **common** side effect when any of the user data fields changes.

Comment: The common side effect is to update my in-memory users cache (which doesn't depend on the current user session), in order to have the most up-to-date data in both sides, my LRU cache and my current user context.

Comment: @Raul - I barely understood any of that. You can absolutely await a dispatch if you `thunk` it See https://medium.com/solute-labs/configuring-thunk-action-creators-and-redux-dev-tools-with-reacts-usereducer-hook-5a1608476812. But I still don't understand the rest of it. I do urge you, though, that whatever you're doing, you've drastically overcomplicated it and should take a step back. Maybe [`use-context-selector`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/use-context-selector) might also help you out here

Comment: I really am not trying to be demeaning. But, as a lead, this type of stuff would never get through PR review

Comment: I agree with @Adam. Plus, the thunk middleware allows you to write actions that return functions in which you can await promises and then handle both their success and/or failure.

Comment: @Adam, why do you think I am doing it wrong? My purpose is to synchronize my users cache (no sensitive user data; if the user signs out, the cache can be reusable with other user sessions) with my context state (sensitive data that depends on the current user session; if the user logs out, then the context will be unmounted). As I am managing the state updates with a reducer, in order to avoid updating my cache inside the dispatch pure function, I am doing this stuff inside a useEffect. I will write the code in the question.

Comment: @Raul - if you're stringifying your dependency, it sounds like you might've mutated it as well (have you?) and are trying to wrangle your way out of it. Mutations = really bad in react. Also, don't get so hung up on pure functions not having side effects - thunks - as much as people think they aren't as kosher as more (way more) complex solutions like sagas, can get you really really far.

Comment: @Adam I have updated the question with my current code. The JSON.stringify is returning the same data but with disorder fields for nested objects. It happens when I do a pull-to-refresh. I simply refresh the user profile and directly update the current user data in the context (the method I use for this is in the code I shared , "updateUser") with the merge option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think (and I could be wrong) this whole problem goes away if you use this effect:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if(!data) return;

  // do some stuff 
},[data]);
```

Comment: I have tried this, but it seems that, as I am doing a pull-to-refresh (using firebase client sdk) and then updating the state data, the new object ref is different. Also, for some reason, the server is returning the data disordered for nested objects :D SO... that seems to be the reason of my problem. THX man for your help anyways.

Comment: @Raul I have a feeling you might be interested in [hashcode](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hashcode) here. If the object hashes are the same on pull-to-refresh, don't do anything.

Comment: thx man for the idea of generating hashcodes to conditionally update state. I have also written a solution to my problem using hooks. It is not as efficient as yours, but will avoid writing some extra code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem I was having was that my server was retuning JSON data with disordered fields... So, you can try both of the current solutions.

@Adam's answer is great, and avoid playing with custom hooks. In its solution, he just generate a hash with the JSON object, and compare with the previous one. If equal hashes, then do not update state, avoiding running the useEffect.

But, this might make you write some conditions and generate hashes in different parts of your code... So, if you don't care about deep comparing your object, you can try this hook:

```
import { useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import { isEqual } from "lodash";

export default function useDeepEffect(
  effect,
  deps = undefined,
  options = { ignoreFirstExecution: false }
) {
  const isFirst = useRef(true);
  const prevDeps = useRef(deps);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isFirst.current || !options.ignoreFirstExecution) {
      const isSame = prevDeps.current.every((obj, index) =>
        isEqual(obj, deps[index])
      );

      if (isFirst.current || !isSame) {
        effect();
      }
    }

    isFirst.current = false;
    prevDeps.current = deps;
  }, deps);
}
```

with the option ignoreFirstExecution set to true, you get the same behavior as using the typical useDidUpdateEffect.

```
  useDeepEffect(
    () => {
      usersCache.updateCachedUser(data.id, data);
    },
    [data],
    { ignoreFirstExecution: true }   
  );
```

Comment: Just an FYI, the [eslint-plugin-react-hooks](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-react-hooks) discourages the behavior of not explcitly defining the dependencies in the deps array, and for good reason - it leads to hard to reason about (i.e. buggy) code. React has been excellent at creating tools (and crafting their own API) to prevent their users from writing buggy code (to the extent possible).

Comment: @Raul I have noticed an optimization in your code. If you are receiving JSON data (may include disorder fields) then, just after the receiving it, you could order its fields. The purpose is to avoid updating your state when not necessary. If you have a look at your main problem, your useDidUpdateEffect is running because of the unnecessary state update! Another solution could be to conditionally update it using deep equality (lodash's isEqual).

Comment: BTW, the solution to your problem is not really easy. There might be a lot of solutions! Your idea of using that custom hook is not bad at all, but you should avoid the unnecessary state update, not the effect!!

Comment: @VictorMolina - that's a really good sum up of the problem that didn't call out explicitly (but is address via the hashcode solution). All the complicated effects in the world won't fix an unnecessary state update.